# How to use $in within golang?

Tags: mongodb, go

In documentation i haven’t found any example of it.
In mongo bash (Compass), i use it:

```
db.inventory.find( { quantity: { $in: [ 5, 15 ] } }, { _id: 0 } )
```

and it works, but if i use this code in golang, i get null:

```
type List struct {
    SortKey   string  `json:"sortKey"`
    SortValue int64   `json:"sortValue"`
    Limit     int64   `json:"limit"`
    Skip      int64   `json:"skip"`
    Arr        []int64 `json:"body"`
}
```

```
opts := options.Find().SetProjection(bson.M{"username": 1, "title": 1}).SetLimit(data.Limit).SetSkip(data.Skip).SetSort(bson.D{{Key: data.SortKey, Value: data.SortValue}})
filter := bson.M{"field": bson.M{"$in": data.Arr}}
cursor, _ := users.Find(ctx, filter, opts)
cursor.All(ctx, &list)
```

If i remove filter := bson.M{“field”: bson.M{"$in": data.Arr}}, then it works, but with it no…

Comment: Isn't that going to be `bson.M{"quantity": bson.M{"$in":data.Arr}}`

Comment: Use `quantity` in the filter doc, not `field`. And use a type for the result documents that can actually model them, `List` is just a single document and it's not for the result. For a quick test use `[]bson.M` like: `var docs []bson.M; cursor.All(ctx, &docs)`

Comment: And always, always check errors, you religiously omit checking them!